# Why does my javascript navigation menu not work on ipads, iphones or Mac Notebooks?

Tags: javascript, ios, iphone, ipad

Why does my javascript navigation menu not work on ipads, iphones or Mac Notebooks?

Here is the navigation:
http://www.newsite0914.i4dsign.co.uk/portfolio.html#portfolio_nav

The Javascript page is:
http://www.newsite0914.i4dsign.co.uk/main.js

The code starts at

```
"function toggleContentWebsite() {
```

Comment: Include the relevant parts of your code in your question by editing it.

Comment: works fine on my mac laptop. works on my iphone as well but i have to tap the links twice. i guess the problem is that the link is only on the textual items and not on the images. dont use onclick. use a binding `$("#element").bind("click", toggle())` or similar.

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time to look into this for me. Good to know its working on your iphone and ipad. Will look into binding.